# Resize An Image

Tags: jquery, html, css

StackOverFlow.
I'm a newbie and I have a question. Hopefully someone can help me. I would like to know how I can resize the images from this amazing [Tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/19/ideas-for-subtle-hover-effects/). I have my own website, the hover effects work just great but I don't know how to resize an image. Based on the code found on
the website posted above, I would like to ask for your help.
Your answers would be highly appreciated !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Resizing is usually a server side affair.  There are a number of tools out there depending on what back end you have.  Resizing can be done in the browser, but you have to take into account older browsers that don't support things such as the canvas.  If you just want to display an image at a different size then CSS is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the standard with of a figure is 33,33%

```
<figure class="effect-lily">

    <img alt="img01" src="img/1.jpg"></img>
    <figcaption></figcaption>

</figure>

.grid figure {
    width: 33.333%;
}
```

If you change this property to 50% for example you'll have 2 images per row. In this example it is under css/component.css on line 22.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand your question.

each image container is a HTML figure tag. So to resize the image, you would really need to resize its container.

Add this into your css under the figure selector

```
width: 200%;
```

If you want another size, just play around with the value =).

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following in your html

```
<img class="myImageClass" src="myImg.png >
```

and then do the resize of the image in your css

```
.myImageClass { width: x; height: y; }
```

where x and y are your new image dimensions.

As a note, you should only decrease, and never increase, the dimensions of an image in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming this is the example `<img src="img/1.jpg" alt="img01"/>`

If so I recommend you change it so something like `<img src="img/1.jpg" Class="Image1" alt="img01"/>`

then in your css add

```
.Image1{
Width:*your chosen width, I would recommend % as the other widths are using that*
}
```

I recommend you look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp
It provides a lot of useful help or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS (search top right corner what your looking for)